# Is it possible to Print into a collapsible CellGroup?

Tags: output-formatting, cells

During rather long computation I have intermediate steps `Print`ed with useful information which should be collected for possible use in future inside of the evaluation `Notebook`. When the computation is finished the final results are printed. But there are hundreds of intermediate `Print`s which fill the screen and contain supporting information which is interesting to see during computation but impede reading the final results. I wish to have an ability to collapse the intermediate prints in a `CellGroup`.

Here is an example from the Documentation page for `EvaluationMonitor`:

```
FindRoot[x^2 - 2, {x, 1}, 
 EvaluationMonitor :> Print["x = ", x " x^2 - 2 =", x^2 - 2]]
```

After evaluation of the above we get intermediate results in one collapsable `CellGroup` (note the collapsed cell group selected on the right):

[image: screenshot]

My problem is that my computation involves several cycles with intermediate evaluations and I am forced to `Print` the final results after a cycle is finished. So all the prints by default belong to one cell group. It can be simulated as follows:

```
Do[Print@FindRoot[x^a - 2, {x, 1}, 
   EvaluationMonitor :> Print["x = ", x , ", x^", a, " - 2 = ", x^a - 2]], {a, 1, 3}]
```

How is it possible to have intermediate prints grouped together and collapsible?

Comment: ``Lookup[Developer`CellInformation[#], "FirstCellInGroup"]`` can be useful for automatic collapsing the cell groups.

Answer (score 4):

All the prints belong to one cell group because they all have style `"Print"` which has option `CellGroupingRules->"GraphicsGrouping"` as seen from the "Core.nb" stylesheet. Apparently `Cell`s with this option are grouped together. On the other hand style `"Output"` has `CellGroupingRules->"OutputGrouping"` and such `Cell`s aren't grouped together and also aren't grouped with `"GraphicsGrouping"`.

So for printing the final result of each computational cycle we can use `CellPrint[ExpressionCell[..., "Output"]]` instead of `Print` and get the desired behavior (intermediate cells are collapsed by hand):

```
Do[CellPrint@
  ExpressionCell[
   FindRoot[x^a - 2, {x, 1}, 
    EvaluationMonitor :> 
     Print["x = ", x, ", x^", a, " - 2 = ", x^a - 2]], "Output"], {a, 
  1, 3}]
```

[image: screenshot]

This method is especially handy with `ShowGroupOpener -> True`:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], ShowGroupOpener -> True];

Do[CellPrint@
  ExpressionCell[
   FindRoot[x^a - 2, {x, 1}, 
    EvaluationMonitor :> Print["x = ", x, ", x^", a, " - 2 = ", x^a - 2]], 
   "Output"], {a, 1, 3}]
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This is good, but it would be better with `EvaluationMonitor :> Print["x = ", x , ", x^", a, " - 2 = ", x^a - 2]`. With this change, one can see what the actual exponent of `x` is.

Comment: @m_goldberg Thanks, I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Also, your solution has the drawback that the three results are not put into the output history. It is not possible to retrieve them later with `Out`. Because of this I think you should consider another modification -- changing `FindRoot[...]` to `rule[a] = FindRoot[...]` -- allowing latter access to the results of `FindRoot` as `rule[1]`, `rule[2]`, `rule[3]`.

Comment: @m_goldberg I see your point, but this question is about output formatting. You suggest some  kind of [memoization](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/memoization) which is useful but not strictly related to the question.