# How to print a collapsed cell group?

Tags: output-formatting, cells, printing

I would like to print a group of cells exactly like what I get from this:

```
CellPrint[
   {Cell["Title", "Subsection"], 
    ExpressionCell[b, "Output"], 
    ExpressionCell[c, "Output"]}]
```

but I would like this cell group to be closed when I print it. Is there a way to do this? I saw `OpenerView` but cannot seem to figure out how to use it. I also do not want to create a new Notebook for the output, I want to print below the currently evaluating Cell.

Comment: Related: "[Is it possible to Print into a collapsible CellGroup?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/47231/280)"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The low level cell expression is `Cell`. All those `Text/ExpressionCells` typset to `Cell` at the end, but only in some circumstances. That is if you mix it with low level `Cell` / `Notebook` it won't work. So the point is, either all `Cells` or higher level functions like `CreateDocument/ExpressionCell` etc.

Maybe you can mix it, but I failed and **my rule of thumb is to use low level functions** like mentioned above and `BoxData` `ToBoxes` etc.

For example I'd expect this to work:

```
CellPrint[
 CellGroup[{
   TextCell["Title", "Subsection"],
   ExpressionCell[b, "Output"],
   ExpressionCell[c, "Output"]
   }, 1]
 ]
```

but it seems that `CellPrint` don't cope to well with high level `CellGroup` and the group is opened.

So the low level approach is:

```
NotebookWrite[ 
    EvaluationNotebook[]
  , CellGroupData[{ 
        Cell["Title", "Subsection"]
      , Cell[BoxData @ ToBoxes @ b, "Output"]
      , Cell[BoxData @ ToBoxes @ c, "Output"] 
      }
      , Closed
    ] 
]
```

remember that if you write somewhere where subsequent cells would be automatically grouped by your `Subsection` then the group will be opened to merge them.

You can use `CellGrouping -> Manual` for your notebook but it depends of the context.

Good luck, be aware of:

[Cell @ CellGroupData[... in Cells family](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/151337/5478)

Comment: Thank you very much for adding so much more detail, it's highly appreciated.