# Print into different cell groups inside module

Tags: output-formatting, cells, output, printing

I have a function with the following (simplified) structure:

```
myfunc[someInput_] :=
  Module[{var1, var2, var3},

   var1 = someInput*3;
   Print["text1: ", var1];
   var2 = someInput^5;
   Print["text2: ", var2];
   var3 = var1*var2;
   Print["text3: ", var3];
   Return[var3]
   ];
```

What I would like to do is the following:
For each of the prints, I would like to print first the text (e.g. 'text1') in a single cell, and then the variable (e.g. 'var1') into another cell right underneath and then group just these two cells, such that I could collapse them later on and the only visible thing is the text ('text1').

The problem is that I am trying to find a way **that does not involve the usage of Section, Subsection etc.** since that would interfere with my Notebook layout... I would just like to have standard output cells which I group according to my liking (but 'automatically' within the function).

Based on [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47231/is-it-possible-to-print-into-a-collapsible-cellgroup) I tried:

```
CellPrint@ExpressionCell[Print["text1: "]; Print[var3];, "Output"];
```

but this did not group the two cells and it also prints an additional, empty cell underneath.
So far, I cannot come up with / find anything else and would thus appreciate any input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can observe how grouping is implemented if you do it manually (under the menu `Cell > Grouping > Group Cells`), and then inspect the cell expressions (`Cell > Show Expression`). Cells obtain the [`CellGroupingRules`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellGroupingRules.html) option, with cells in the same group having the same numerical priority.

To emulate this, you can use a global counter that you increase for every new printed group:

```
$GroupCounter = 1000;
printCellGroup[exprs__] := 
 With[{g = $GroupCounter ++}, 
  CellPrint[ExpressionCell[#, "Output", 
      CellGroupingRules -> {"GroupTogetherGrouping", g}] & /@ 
    List@exprs]]

printCellGroup["Text 1", x, x^2]
printCellGroup["Text 2", y, y^3]
```

[image]